# Event Query Using FQL Returns "OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Querying of **certain** events on Facebook using FQL returns `OAuthException: An unknown error`.

Here is an example of a Facebook event query that will return such a result: `SELECT venue.id FROM event WHERE eid = 256040074473355` ([Click Here To Test Query Using Facebook's Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20venue.id%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20%3D%20256040074473355)).

Knowing which events this will happen to is impossible to do programatically until you run into this exception. Related defects have been opened on Facebook's (rather useless) bug tracker ([Click Here For An Example](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/156815164437474?browse=search_4f60efa0628022f78868074)) and as expected, there is essentially no acknowledgement of this issue.

And, yes, I have user_events & friends_events permissions, etc.., etc..

**Does anyone know what's going on and why?**

**UPDATE (as of March 25, 2012):**
Simply adding `AND location` to the end of the query will get it to work ([Click Here To Test Query Using Facebook's Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20venue.id%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20%3D%20256040074473355%20AND%20location)). Not quite sure why  this works but it does the job for the time being. I'll reserve adding this as an *Answer* until there is a real (ie: non-hack) solution.